# Angular can not call google API service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, jsonp, web.xml

I am trying to use google place service

```
$http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels in US&key=XXXXXXXXX&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
})
.success(function(data) {
    console.log('data' + data);
})
.error(function(data) { });
```

API call is OK 200. But on console it gives error XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels%20in%20US&key=XXXXU&callback=JSON_CALLBACK. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://192.168.1.85:8443' is therefore not allowed access.

I change method:JSONP then it returns data but with syntax error like : required. My server is tomcat 7. I am also using CORS filtercom.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter .

Comment: Missing `{` after `$http(`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$http()` to `$http.jsonp(url).succes....`

Comment: It returns data but with syntax error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :